# \noalign changes the location of the number of equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I just found that `\noalign` can change the number to the bottom. But usually one expect it appears at the middle. If I comment `\noalign{choose $\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1}$ with $\mathcal{F}(\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1} )\le\min(\vec{F}({\vec{x}'}^{n-1}),\vec{F}(\vec{x}'))$}\\`, the location of the number is fine. How should one keep the number in the right location but also use `\noalign`?

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{  
  \begin{align}
    \vec{x}&=\vec{x}^{n-1}+\alpha(\vec{u}-\vec{x}^{n-1})\\
   \overline{\vec{y}}&=\vec{y}+\alpha(\nabla\mathcal{F}(\vec{x})-\vec{y})\\
   \overline{\gamma}&=\gamma+\alpha(\mathcal{F}(\vec{x})-\avg{\nabla{F}(\vec{x}),\vec{x}}-\gamma)\\
    {\vec{x}'}^{n-1}&=\argmin\limits_{\vec{z}\in\bra{\vec{x},\vec{x}^{n-1}}}\mathcal{F}(\vec{z})\\
    {\gamma'}^{n-1}&=\overline{\gamma}-\mathcal{F}({\vec{x'}^{n-1}})\\
    \vec{u}'&=\mathcal{U}({{\gamma'}^{n-1}},\overline{\vec{y}})\\
    \vec{x}'&=\vec{x}^{n-1}+\alpha(\vec{u}'-\vec{x}^{n-1})\\
   \noalign{choose $\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1}$ with $\mathcal{F}(\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1} )\le\min(\vec{F}({\vec{x}'}^{n-1}),\vec{F}(\vec{x}'))$}\\
      \overline{\gamma}^n&=\overline{\gamma}-\mathcal{F}(\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1})\\
      \overline{\vec{u}}&=\mathcal{U}(\overline{\gamma}^n,\overline{\vec{y}})\\
       \overline{\eta}&=\mathcal{E}(\overline{\gamma}^n,\overline{\vec{y}})\\
       \vec{x}^n&=\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1}\\
   \end{align}
\right.
 \end{equation}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code also throws an error: `Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;`

Comment: after an error don't look at the pdf at all, tex will only recover enough to try to syntax check the remaining document, it does not try to make usable typeset output.  The `align` environment _starts_ math mode so it should not be inside `equation`.

Comment: `\noalign` isn't a command intended for top level use in a latex document, it is used internally in package code. perhaps you are looking for `\intertext{some text here}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is that `align` can not be used in math mode. I also guessed definitions for your undefined commands, and fixed the double subscript errors.

`\noalign` is not a user-level command to be used in a document. Normally in `align` you could use `\intertext` but here in `aligned` I just used `\rlap`.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\avg{avg}
\DeclareMathOperator\argmin{argmin}
\newcommand\bra[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{  
  \begin{aligned}
    \vec{x}&=\vec{x}^{n-1}+\alpha(\vec{u}-\vec{x}^{n-1})\\
   \overline{\vec{y}}&=\vec{y}+\alpha(\nabla\mathcal{F}(\vec{x})-\vec{y})\\
   \overline{\gamma}&=\gamma+\alpha(\mathcal{F}(\vec{x})-\avg{\nabla{F}(\vec{x}),\vec{x}}-\gamma)\\
    {\vec{x}'{}}^{n-1}&=\argmin\limits_{\vec{z}\in\bra{\vec{x},\vec{x}^{n-1}}}\mathcal{F}(\vec{z})\\
    {\gamma'}^{n-1}&=\overline{\gamma}-\mathcal{F}({\vec{x'}^{n-1}})\\
    \vec{u}'&=\mathcal{U}({{\gamma'}^{n-1}},\overline{\vec{y}})\\
    \vec{x}'&=\vec{x}^{n-1}+\alpha(\vec{u}'-\vec{x}^{n-1})\\
   \rlap{\hspace{-2em}choose $\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1}$ with $\mathcal{F}(\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1} )\le
\min(\vec{F}({\vec{x}'{}}^{n-1}),\vec{F}(\vec{x}'))$}\\
      \overline{\gamma}^n&=\overline{\gamma}-\mathcal{F}(\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1})\\
      \overline{\vec{u}}&=\mathcal{U}(\overline{\gamma}^n,\overline{\vec{y}})\\
       \overline{\eta}&=\mathcal{E}(\overline{\gamma}^n,\overline{\vec{y}})\\
       \vec{x}^n&=\overline{\vec{x}}^{n-1}\\
   \end{aligned}
\right.
 \end{equation}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\multispan{2}`