# Using `shortintertext` with `gathered` environment

Tags: equations, gather, intertext

I am currently using `amsmath`'s `gather` environment to display a list of (long) expressions.   I also want to insert the text "and", for which I use `mathtools`'s `\shortintertext`, like so:

```
...and hence the quantities \begin{gather*}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 \\
\shortintertext{and}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_2
\end{gather*} must all vanish.
```

For later in my document, I also want to label this list of expressions with *one* number.

If I weren't using `intertext` or `shortintertext`, this could be done using the `gathered` environment, nested inside `equation`:

```
...and hence the quantities \begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 \\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_2
end{gathered}  \label{eqn:commonValues}
\end{equation} must all vanish.  The values in \cref{eqn:commonValues} also appear later.
```

But when I try to use this with `shortintertext`, I get

```
! Package amsmath Error: Invalid use of \shortintertext.
```

on MikTeX.  **How can I use both `gathered` and `\shortintertext`?**

MnWE: just wrap the second code snippet above in

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
INSERT HERE!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide copy-pastable code which reproduces the error. `INSERT HERE!` is just going to produce a PDF with 'INSERT HERE!' and not the error you want help with.

Comment: `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` make clear distinction that you have two (set of)  equations, therefore they can not be referred as one. so you cant use `\shortintertext` and `gather` together.

Comment: ups. should be `gathered` instead `gather`.

Comment: @Zarko: I can't use  `\intertext` as well as `\shortintertext` within `gathered` nested in `equation`. If I nest  gathered in a `gather` instead of `equation`, it compiles without problem, but… everything is aligned at the left margin.

Comment: @Bernard, yes it works, however equation number is  on wrong place after `gather` ...  maybe latex by this defend against illogical use of amsmath/mathtools math environments :-) from math aspect is what to try op, wrong.

Comment: you could use `\rlap` as here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333101/noalign-changes-the-location-of-the-number-of-equation/333115#333115

Answer (score 1):

to my opinion is the way, what you like to obtain, wrong. the cloest possibiliti which cross my mind is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:commonValues}
\begin{gather}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1    
\shortintertext{with correct use of "intertext/shortintertext"}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_2    
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
see \eqref{eqn:commonValues}.
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

as i mentioned in my comments above, `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` make clear distinction that you have two (set of) equations, which are interrupted by inserted text. therefore they can not be treated nor referred as one. so you can't use \shortintertext`nor`\intertext`and`gathered` together. this is also wrong (to my opinion) from math aspect too.

somehow wrongly works the following (as mentioned [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his comment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eqn:commonValues-2}
\begin{gathered}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 
\shortintertext{and}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_2
\end{gathered}
\end{gather}
see \eqref{eqn:commonValues-2}.
\end{document}
```

but result is useless:

[image]

it seems that the (la)text on this way defend itself from illogical use of their math environments. more details, how it doing this, can explain authors of `amsmath˙ package. maybe some of them will respond :-)